# Publish Cobertura Code Coverage XML from Jenkins to GitLab

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, code-coverage, cobertura

I'm trying to find a way to publish a Cobertura code-coverage XML from Jenkins to GitLab.
I've got Gitlab triggering Jenkins pipelines which generates a Cobertura code-coverage report, and currently publishes it in Jenkins.

I know  Gitlab supports Test Coverage Visualization  via GitLab CI/CD’s artifacts reports feature, is there any way I can publish the report generated by Jenkins to Gitlab so that I can use Gitlab's visualization?

I know Jenkins reports the build status back to Gitlab, I'd just like for Jenkins to report the code coverage back to Gitlab as well.

Comment: Obvious question, why not have gitlab generate the code coverage in CI and have Jenkins just download it as an artifact?

Comment: @Zach I have a similar problem. Did you solve yours?

Comment: @hammer89 yeah I just moved.the whole build process to the Gitlab CI with Runners 